# Global variable update from thread and access from main in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, global

i have the particular program..

```
node_up = [0,0,0,0,0]
list_host = [ '10.0.2.12', '10.0.2.13', '10.0.2.14', '10.0.2.15', '10.0.2.16' ]

def node_check():
    global node_up, list_host
    for i in range( len(list_host) ):
        try:
            b = subprocess.check_output( ["ping", "-c", "4", "-w", "4", list_host[i] ] )
            print b
            node_up[i] = 1
            print node_up
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
            print e.output
            node_up[i] = 0
            print node_up


thread.start_new_thread( node_check(), () )
while(1):
    print "round"
    if 0 in node_up:
        print "not up"
        print node_up
    else:
        print "up"
        print node_up
    print "round"
    time.sleep(5)
```

I expect this program to print `not up` wen any ping is unsuccesfull, and `up` wen all ping is successful.. the function `node_check()` is executing coz the prints are coming properly with the `node_up` array.. But the program never seem to execute the main `while(1)` which checks for the `node_up`

Can anyone point out wat i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the definition of the [`start_new_thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) function, the first parameter should be a function object. But you are passing the result of calling the function. So, change it like this

```
thread.start_new_thread(node_check, ())
```

Now a new thread will be created and it will execute the `node_check` function.

Comment: thanks man.. such a silly mistake.. its working now..will accept in 8 minutes..  :)

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a silly way to do this. Why don't you refactor to use `queue.Queue`s instead?

```
import queue
import threading
import subprocess

QUEUE_TIMEOUT = 5
NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 5

HOST_LIST = ['10.0.2.12', '10.0.2.13', '10.0.2.14',
             '10.0.2.15', '10.0.2.16']

def node_check(host_q, response_q):
    try:
        host = host_q.get(timeout=QUEUE_TIMEOUT)
    except queue.Empty:
        return
    try:
        b = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "4", "-w", "4", host])
        response_q.put(True, timeout=QUEUE_TIMEOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        response_q.put(False, timeout=QUEUE_TIMEOUT)
    host_q.task_done()

def main():
    host_queue = queue.Queue()
    response_queue = queue.Queue()

    for host in HOST_LIST:
        host_queue.put(host)


    threadlist = [threading.Thread(target=node_check,
                                   args=(host_queue, response_queue)) for
                  _ in range(NUM_WORKER_THREADS)]
    for t in threadlist:
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    host_queue.join() # wait for all hosts to be processed
    if all(host_queue.queue):
        # all nodes are up
    else:
        # some node is down
```